# US NRC and CNSC policy towards Native/First People's land in building nuclear reactors there

Tags: tribal

In the US, Amerindians often have limited but ample jurisdiction over their own tribal territories, being able to build their own casinos as long as it's on Amerindian Land.

Because of my goal to create my own nuclear reactor, I am wondering if the US Nuclear Regulatory Commission (US NRC) or Canada Nuclear Safety Commission (CNSC) would have to be notified of its creation if I somehow get permission from the Amerindians to build a reactor on their territory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[42 USC Ch. 73](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/42/chapter-73/subchapter-II) gives the Nuclear Regulatory Commission the power to regulates nuclear facilities pursuant to the Atomic Energy Act. Those laws and regulations apply the United States in general, not just to the States, so you definitely have to get federal approval and not just tribal approval. There are no doubt state-level requirements for building a reactor, but they are not applicable to tribal land, analogous to the casino situation. Congress did not exempt any tribes from that law, so all such federal regulations are in force against your scheme. The NRC kindly provides [a page](https://tribal.nrc.gov/) telling you of related shipment-notification requirements, if you plan to ship regulated materials across their land.

Comment: I see, thank you! Off to international waters, it is.

Comment: @YoungJunLee Make sure you're flagged under a non-IAEA member state and non-Non Proliferation Treaty state because both impose requirements. How well do you get along with North Korea or South Sudan?